# Neo4j Spring Data NodeEntity use String as @id

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to use a java.lang.String as the @Id of a NodeEntity.

```
 @NodeEntity(label = "MachineType")
 public class MachineType {
     @Id private String id;
     ....
```

It should be possible acording to the spring data neo4j docu:

```
While an id is still required on all entities, the behavior has been
simplified by introducing the new @Id annotation. It replaces both
@GraphId and the primary attribute and can be placed on any attribute 
with a simple type.
```

When I'm trying to insert I get a:

```
{
    "cause": null,
    "message": "Id must be assignable to Serializable!: null"
}
```

Which is strange, because String implements the Serializable.
Anyone has an idea where to search next?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot use anything else as an ID. Keep in mind that this Long number will be reused if you delete the node.

I use [UUID](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) plugin to generate true unique keys and when I use spring-data-rest I use BackendIdConverter to change the id to the uuid for the resources that I expose.

Example:
Model:

```
@NodeEntity
@Data
public class Target {

    @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;   // <----Neo4j id 

    private String uuid;           // <----My Key

    @Version Long version;
    private List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_MEDIA", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Gallery> media = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Convert resource id to my key:

```
@Component 
public class MovieIdConverter implements BackendIdConverter {
    @Autowired MovieRepo movieRepository;

    @Override
    public Serializable fromRequestId(String id, Class<?> entityType) {
        Movie movie = movieRepository.findByUuid(id);
        return  (Serializable) movie.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public String toRequestId(Serializable serializable, Class<?> aClass) {
        Long id = (Long) serializable;
        Optional<Movie> movie = movieRepository.findById(id);
        if (movie.isPresent()) return movie.get().getUuid();
        return null;
}

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return Movie.class.equals(aClass);
    }
}
```